# A question from the tightness of measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to prove the following two parts of the question.

a) Show that $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight if and only if for each $\epsilon$ there is a compact set $K$ such that $\mu_n(K)>1- \epsilon$ for all $n$.

b) Show that $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight if and only if each of the k sequences of marginal distributions is tight on the line.

I know that

A sequence $\{\mu_n\}$ of probability measures is tight if for every $\epsilon$ there is a bounded rectangle $A$ such that $\mu_n(A)>1-\epsilon$ for all $n$.

By this definition, we know that a bounded rectangle $A$ in $R^k$ is compact. This implies $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight.

This does not looks good to me.The question is basically asking to prove the definition.

Can anyone help to solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

More frequently we use a) as the definition because we don't always have a rectangle in our space. If you are only considering $\mathbb{R}^k$, then he equivalence between your rectangle definition and a) should be easy to establish because every compact set in $\mathbb{R}^k$ is bounded and closed.

For b), for simplicity let me only write the case $k=2$. The idea remains the same.

"if" part: Say for the two marginals we have compact $K_1,K_2$. Then just take rectangle to be $K_1\times K_2$ and notice that $$(K_1\times K_2)^c\subset(K_1\times R)^c\cup(R\times K_2)^c.$$

"only if" part: for two dimensional compact $K$, just take $K_i=\pi_i(K),i=1,2$ to be the compact sets for the two marginals.

Comment: I understand the part a). Part b) is not clear to me like how the definition is helpful to prove part b). Can you please give me little more clarity for part b)?

Comment: @User124356: I've added the detail to my answer.